# FTP into an external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ftp, ip-camera

I have a linux machine with kubuntu 20.04 and a stupid IP camera which uses FTP protocol. If I tell to FTP into /media/camera (which is an external HD mounted in /media) it FTP in /home/user/media/camera. So it creates a /media folder with a /camera subfolder into my home and user folder!

I already tried to create a link to the HD into the /home/user folder but it does not work. Is there a solution or a workaround for this ?

Comment: Modify the config of the FTP server (ie modify its root) You might want to advise what FTP server you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am using ProFTPd as FTP server.  Can you please tell me what line to modify in the /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf file ? Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean "DefaultRoot" I uncomment it and set it to the /media/camera folder and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to question title. Instead post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. The question will then appear as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! But I can mark it as accepted after 2 days ....what a weird site :)

Comment: That's to prevent users from prematurely accepting a "good enough" answer if a question is still relatively new and a better answer could be posted soon. You're probably used to forums, which are built with open-ended discussion in mind and require workarounds such as adding "SOLVED" to mark solved problems. This website is built for problem solving and constant improvement, hence we have a dedicated system for marking solutions and answers are ordered by quality rather than chronologically.

Comment: That makes sense :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DefaultRoot" uncommented in the /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf file and set it to the /media/camera folder and it works!